# Determining Fantasy Football Optimal Rosters in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have downloaded all of the data from my fantasy football league and have been doing some analysis in R. One thing I am struggling to do is figure out a way to determine what would have been each players optimal team each week. That is, each player in my league chose a set of their players to start and a set of their players to bench. In hindsight, we know what each player actually scored and can determine whether or not the player chose correctly.

My data is structured in the following way:

- Team = Fantasy Team (2 included in example 10 in total)
- Week = What week this occurred on (1 included in example 16 in total)
- Slot = What position this player was played in
- Player = Players name
- Position = Players NFL position
- FPTS = Points Scored

```
structure(list(Team = c("Washington Beersnake", "Washington Beersnake", 
"Washington Beersnake", "Washington Beersnake", "Washington Beersnake", 
"Washington Beersnake", "Washington Beersnake", "Washington Beersnake", 
"Washington Beersnake", "Washington Beersnake", "Washington Beersnake", 
"Washington Beersnake", "Washington Beersnake", "Washington Beersnake", 
"Washington Beersnake", "Washington Beersnake", "Dimmadome Doug", 
"Dimmadome Doug", "Dimmadome Doug", "Dimmadome Doug", "Dimmadome Doug", 
"Dimmadome Doug", "Dimmadome Doug", "Dimmadome Doug", "Dimmadome Doug", 
"Dimmadome Doug", "Dimmadome Doug", "Dimmadome Doug", "Dimmadome Doug", 
"Dimmadome Doug", "Dimmadome Doug", "Dimmadome Doug"), Week = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), SLOT = c("QB", "RB", "RB", "WR/TE", 
"WR/TE", "WR/TE", "FLEX", "D/ST", "K", "Bench", "Bench", "Bench", 
"Bench", "Bench", "Bench", "Bench", "QB", "RB", "RB", "WR/TE", 
"WR/TE", "WR/TE", "FLEX", "D/ST", "K", "Bench", "Bench", "Bench", 
"Bench", "Bench", "Bench", "Bench"), PLAYER = c("Justin Herbert", 
"Alvin Kamara", "Saquon Barkley", "Terry McLaurin", "Keenan Allen", 
"Brandon Aiyuk", "Myles Gaskin", "Buccaneers D/ST", "Matt Gay", 
"William Fuller V", "AJ Dillon", "Marvin Jones Jr.", "Justin Fields", 
"Jalen Reagor", "J.D. McKissic", "Darnell Mooney", "Kyler Murray", 
"David Montgomery", "Miles Sanders", "Tyreek Hill", "DK Metcalf", 
"DeVonta Smith", "Raheem Mostert", "Washington D/ST", "Younghoe Koo", 
"Javonte Williams", "Corey Davis", "Matt Ryan", "Henry Ruggs III", 
"Curtis Samuel", "Nyheim Hines", "Tony Pollard"), Position = c("QB", 
"RB", "RB", "WR", "WR", "WR", "RB", "D/ST", "K", "WR", "RB", 
"WR", "QB", "WR", "RB", "WR", "QB", "RB", "WR", "WR", "WR", "WR", 
"WR", "D/ST", "K", "RB", "WR", "QB", "WR", "WR", "RB", "RB"), 
    FPTS = c(15.38, 15.1, 2.7, 6.2, 10, 0, 7.6, 3, 12, 0, 2.6, 
    13.7, 6.7, 10.9, 0.8, 2.6, 41.56, 17.8, 13.3, 26.1, 12, 13.1, 
    2, 4, 6, 4.1, 21.7, 7.36, 4.6, 0, 8.2, 4.3)), row.names = c(NA, 
-32L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

[image: Data Example]

I would like to add a new column to the end of the data frame called "optimal slot". The logic for this would be as follows.

- QB = highest scoring player with QB position on the team that week
- RB1 = highest scoring player with RB position on the team that week
- RB2 = second highest scoring player with RB position on the team that week
- WR/TE1 = highest scoring player with WR or TE position on the team that week
- WR/TE2 = second highest scoring player with WR or TE position on the team that week
- WR/TE3 = third highest scoring player with WR or TE position on the team that week
- RB/WR/TE = highest remaining player with RB/WR/TE position on the team that week
- D/ST = highest scoring player with D/ST position on the team that week
- K = highest scoring player with K position on the team that week
- BENCH = all remaining players on the team that week

This needs to be figured out for each player each week (the reason 2 players were included in data example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it easier to *tackle* this with some reference tables.  The FLEX slot makes things a little tricky in that we have to find the optimal selections first and then pick the best remaining eligible player.

Anyway, this is probably overkill but should scale nicely.

```
library(tidyverse)

#ASSUME ORIGINAL DATA IS STORED AS df

#To start, it might be helpful to have some reference tables.
#First, what positions are eligible to be placed in what slots?
possible_slots <- tibble(Position = c("QB", "RB", "RB", "WR", "WR", "TE", "TE", "D/ST", "K"),
               possible_slot = c("QB", "RB", "FLEX", "WR/TE", "FLEX", "WR/TE", "FLEX", "D/ST", "K"))

#Next, for each slot, how many players can be selected?
topn <- tibble(possible_slot = c("QB", "RB", "WR/TE", "D/ST", "K"),
               n_slots = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 1))

#Ok, now let's create a record for every potential slot that a player could conceivably take
all_possible_slots <- df %>% 
  left_join(possible_slots, by = "Position") %>% 
  left_join(topn, by = "possible_slot") %>% 
  #For each team, week and possible slot, rank the possiblity by points (descending)
  group_by(Team, Week, possible_slot) %>% 
  #Note the use of ties.method = first to ensure only one record per rank
  mutate(rank = rank(-FPTS, ties.method = "first")) %>% 
  ungroup()

#Now limit just to those records where the rank is <= the number of available slots
optimal_slots <- all_possible_slots %>% 
  filter(rank <= n_slots)

#The FLEX slot is special case, we need to select the best REMAINING player,
#i.e. one not selected in optimal_slots
flex_slot <- all_possible_slots %>% 
  #limit just to the FLEX slot and remove anyone selected in optimal_slots
  filter(possible_slot == "FLEX") %>% 
  anti_join(optimal_slots %>% select(Team, Week, PLAYER)) %>% 
  #Among those remaining, take the highest scoring
  group_by(Team, Week) %>% 
  filter(rank(-FPTS, ties.method = "first") == 1) %>% 
  ungroup() 

#Now let's bring it all together with the original data.
df %>% 
  #append the optimal slot (including flex)
  left_join({
    optimal_slots %>% 
      bind_rows(flex_slot) %>% 
      #concatenate the slot and the rank in that slot
      mutate(optimal_slot = paste0(possible_slot, 
                                   ifelse(possible_slot %in% c("RB", "WR/TE"), rank, ""))) %>% 
      select(Team, Week, PLAYER, optimal_slot)
  }, by = c("Team", "Week", "PLAYER")) %>% 
  #Anyone without an optimal slot should be benched
  mutate(optimal_slot = coalesce(optimal_slot, "BENCH"))


# A tibble: 32 x 7
Team                  Week SLOT  PLAYER           Position  FPTS optimal_slot
<chr>                <dbl> <chr> <chr>            <chr>    <dbl> <chr>       
  1 Washington Beersnake     1 QB    Justin Herbert   QB        15.4 QB          
2 Washington Beersnake     1 RB    Alvin Kamara     RB        15.1 RB1         
3 Washington Beersnake     1 RB    Saquon Barkley   RB         2.7 BENCH       
4 Washington Beersnake     1 WR/TE Terry McLaurin   WR         6.2 FLEX        
5 Washington Beersnake     1 WR/TE Keenan Allen     WR        10   WR/TE3      
6 Washington Beersnake     1 WR/TE Brandon Aiyuk    WR         0   BENCH       
7 Washington Beersnake     1 FLEX  Myles Gaskin     RB         7.6 RB2         
8 Washington Beersnake     1 D/ST  Buccaneers D/ST  D/ST       3   D/ST        
9 Washington Beersnake     1 K     Matt Gay         K         12   K           
10 Washington Beersnake     1 Bench William Fuller V WR         0   BENCH       
# ... with 22 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it in base--define a function that filters your input dataframe using your logic, sorts the result by FPTS, and assigns the corresponding position in `optimal_slot`. Then apply over weeks and teams.

```
# Where `ss` is your input data for a single week and team
optimal_ff <- function(ss){
  
  # Baseline is BENCH for all players
  ss$optimal_slot <- "BENCH"
  
  # Top individual positions
  ss[ss$FPTS %in% sort(ss[ss$Position == "QB", "FPTS"], decreasing = TRUE)[1] &
       ss$Position == "QB", "optimal_slot"] <- "QB"
  
  ss[ss$FPTS %in% sort(ss[ss$Position %in% c("D/ST"), "FPTS"], decreasing = TRUE)[1] &
       ss$Position %in% c("D/ST"), "optimal_slot"] <- "D/ST"
  
  ss[ss$FPTS %in% sort(ss[ss$Position %in% c("K"), "FPTS"], decreasing = TRUE)[1] &
       ss$Position %in% c("K"), "optimal_slot"] <- "K"
  
  # Top two RBs
  ss[ss$FPTS %in% sort(ss[ss$Position == "RB", "FPTS"], decreasing = TRUE)[1:2] &
       ss$Position == "RB", "optimal_slot"] <- c("RB1", "RB2")
  
  # Top three WR/TE
  ss[ss$FPTS %in% sort(ss[ss$Position %in% c("WR", "TE"), "FPTS"], decreasing = TRUE)[1:3] &
       ss$Position %in% c("WR", "TE"), "optimal_slot"] <- c("WR/TE", "WR/TE", "WR/TE")
  
  # Top remaining RB/WR/TE
  ss[ss$FPTS %in% sort(ss[ss$Position %in% c("RB", "WR", "TE") & ss$optimal_slot == "BENCH", "FPTS"], decreasing = TRUE)[1] &
       ss$Position %in% c("RB", "WR", "TE") &
       ss$optimal_slot == "BENCH", "optimal_slot"] <- "RB/WR/TE"
  
  return(ss$optimal_slot)
}
```

Example of using the function on all weeks/teams:

```
weeks <- unique(df$Week)
teams <- unique(df$Team)
for(week in weeks){
  for(team in teams){
    df[df$Team == team & df$Week == week, "optimal_slot"] <- optimal_ff(df[df$Team == team & df$Week == week,])
  }
}

df[order(df$Team, df$optimal_slot, decreasing=TRUE),]
#>                    Team Week  SLOT           PLAYER Position  FPTS optimal_slot
#> 5  Washington Beersnake    1 WR/TE     Keenan Allen       WR 10.00        WR/TE
#> 12 Washington Beersnake    1 Bench Marvin Jones Jr.       WR 13.70        WR/TE
#> 14 Washington Beersnake    1 Bench     Jalen Reagor       WR 10.90        WR/TE
#> 7  Washington Beersnake    1  FLEX     Myles Gaskin       RB  7.60          RB2
#> 2  Washington Beersnake    1    RB     Alvin Kamara       RB 15.10          RB1
#> 4  Washington Beersnake    1 WR/TE   Terry McLaurin       WR  6.20     RB/WR/TE
#> 1  Washington Beersnake    1    QB   Justin Herbert       QB 15.38           QB
#> 9  Washington Beersnake    1     K         Matt Gay        K 12.00            K
#> 8  Washington Beersnake    1  D/ST  Buccaneers D/ST     D/ST  3.00         D/ST
#> 3  Washington Beersnake    1    RB   Saquon Barkley       RB  2.70        BENCH
#> 6  Washington Beersnake    1 WR/TE    Brandon Aiyuk       WR  0.00        BENCH
#> 10 Washington Beersnake    1 Bench William Fuller V       WR  0.00        BENCH
#> 11 Washington Beersnake    1 Bench        AJ Dillon       RB  2.60        BENCH
#> 13 Washington Beersnake    1 Bench    Justin Fields       QB  6.70        BENCH
#> 15 Washington Beersnake    1 Bench    J.D. McKissic       RB  0.80        BENCH
#> 16 Washington Beersnake    1 Bench   Darnell Mooney       WR  2.60        BENCH
#> 19       Dimmadome Doug    1    RB    Miles Sanders       WR 13.30        WR/TE
#> 20       Dimmadome Doug    1 WR/TE      Tyreek Hill       WR 26.10        WR/TE
#> 27       Dimmadome Doug    1 Bench      Corey Davis       WR 21.70        WR/TE
#> 31       Dimmadome Doug    1 Bench     Nyheim Hines       RB  8.20          RB2
#> 18       Dimmadome Doug    1    RB David Montgomery       RB 17.80          RB1
#> 22       Dimmadome Doug    1 WR/TE    DeVonta Smith       WR 13.10     RB/WR/TE
#> 17       Dimmadome Doug    1    QB     Kyler Murray       QB 41.56           QB
#> 25       Dimmadome Doug    1     K     Younghoe Koo        K  6.00            K
#> 24       Dimmadome Doug    1  D/ST  Washington D/ST     D/ST  4.00         D/ST
#> 21       Dimmadome Doug    1 WR/TE       DK Metcalf       WR 12.00        BENCH
#> 23       Dimmadome Doug    1  FLEX   Raheem Mostert       WR  2.00        BENCH
#> 26       Dimmadome Doug    1 Bench Javonte Williams       RB  4.10        BENCH
#> 28       Dimmadome Doug    1 Bench        Matt Ryan       QB  7.36        BENCH
#> 29       Dimmadome Doug    1 Bench  Henry Ruggs III       WR  4.60        BENCH
#> 30       Dimmadome Doug    1 Bench    Curtis Samuel       WR  0.00        BENCH
#> 32       Dimmadome Doug    1 Bench     Tony Pollard       RB  4.30        BENCH
Created on 2022-01-12 by the reprex package (v2.0.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

All of your bullet points require the same technique so it is sufficient to solve for a single example:

```r
highest_score = df %>%
  filter(SLOT = "QB") %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  summarise(max_score = max(FTPS))

highest_scoring_player_df = df %>%
  filter(SLOT = "QB",
         FTPS = highest_score) %>%
  select(PLAYER)

highest_scoring_player = highest_scoring_player_df[1,1]

df = df %>%
  mutate(optimal_slot = ifelse(PLAYER == highest_scoring_player, "QB", optimal_slot))
```

After repeating this pattern for each position, you can set `optimal_slot` to `BENCH` for all players who are yet to be assigned an optimal slot:

```r
df = df %>%
  mutate(optimal_slot = ifelse(is.na(optimal_slot), "BENCH", optimal_slot))
```